# In React Navigation 5 in React Native, HeaderShown: false won't hide header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-native-navigation

I've been experimenting in React Native and have noticed the `expo init` command now brings in a newer base codebase to start from. The issue I'm having is related the header not hiding when we use the `headerShown` prop in the options of the navigator component.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import TabBarIcon from "../components/TabBarIcon";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import LinksScreen from "../screens/LinksScreen";

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME = "Home";

export default function BottomTabNavigator({ navigation, route }) {
  // navigation.setOptions({
  //   headerShown: false
  // });

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName={INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME}>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-code-working" />
          )
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Links"
        component={LinksScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name="md-book" />
          )
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The code above is the different methods I've tried to apply the header shown. I have also tried doing it the older way by creating the static method for navigation options in each of the page components. Neither seems to work, and what's annoying is the docs have suggested applying it to the navigator is the way to use it in this version of react-navigation.

The Home page component looks like so:

```js
export default function HomeScreen() {
  return <View style={styles.container}></View>;
}

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  headerShown: false
};
```

And the Links page looks almost identical minus the render function.

Comment: Try setting - headermode: null or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For All Screen on this Stack

```
<LoggedStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false}} >
        <LoggedStack.Screen name='Dash' component={MyDrawer} />
        <LoggedStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
</LoggedStack.Navigator>
```

For Specific Screen

```
<Drawer.Screen name="Dept" component={DepartMentScreen} options={{ headerShown: false}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out the new base code creates a stack navigator that references the screen with the bottom tab navigator applying the header shown prop to the stack navigator disabled the headers on the pages

```js
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
```